# Autoresize Custom UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, custom-controls, uialertview

I made a custom UIAlertView, who look like this

http://www.odlgs.com/customAlertBefore.jpg

The problem  is that when I rotate to another interface orientation the alert change it's size and looks like this:

http://www.odlgs.com/customAlertAfter.jpg

I made a NSNotification that allows me to resize controls when I switch to another interface orientation, but doesn't work with my UIAlertView, and the autoresizingMask property do not works too, anyone that have experience the same problem or has some idea? here is the code:

```
/*** THIS IS THE CLASS OF MY CUSTOM ALERTVIEW ***/
#import "AlertTableViewController.h"
#import "Theme.h"
@implementation AlertTableViewController
@synthesize  textField, caller, context, data;

-(id)initWithCaller:(id)_caller data:(NSArray*)_data title:(NSString*)_title andContext:(id)_context{
    NSMutableString *messageString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"\n"];
    tableHeight = 0;
    if([_data count] != 0){
        for(int i = 0; i < [_data count]; i++){
            //[messageString appendString:@"\n\n"];
            //tableHeight += 53;
            tableHeight = 150;
        }
    }else{
        //messageString = @"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
        tableHeight = 207;
    }

    if(self = [super initWithTitle:_title message:messageString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil]){
        self.caller = _caller;
        self.context = _context;
        self.data = _data;
        [self prepare];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    [self.caller didSelectRowAtIndex:-1 withContext:self.context];
}

-(void)show{
    self.hidden = YES;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(myTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    [super show];
}

-(void)myTimer:(NSTimer*)_timer{
    self.hidden = NO;
    [myTableView flashScrollIndicators];
}

//HERE I ADD THE CONTROLS TO MY CUSTOM ALERTVIEW
-(void)prepare{
    self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(11, 50, 261, 30)];
    textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    textField.delegate = self;
    myTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(11, 115, 261, tableHeight) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    myTableView.scrollEnabled = NO;

    myTableView.delegate = self;
    myTableView.dataSource = self;

    UILabel *sourcesTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(11, 90, 261, 20)];
    sourcesTitle.text = @"Source";
    sourcesTitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    sourcesTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    sourcesTitle.font  = [UIFont fontWithName:kLKTtFONT_NAME size:kLKTtFONT_LABEL_SIZE_17];
    UIButton *ok = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    ok.frame = CGRectMake(11, 280, 120, 30);
    [ok setTitle:@"Ok" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [ok addTarget:self action:@selector(saveNetwork) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    UIButton *cancel = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    cancel.frame = CGRectMake(150, 280, 120, 30);
    [cancel setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cancel addTarget:self action:@selector(cancel) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    [self addSubview:sourcesTitle];
    [self addSubview:ok];
    [self addSubview:cancel];
    [self addSubview:myTableView];
    [self addSubview:textField];

    [textField becomeFirstResponder];

    UIImageView *imgView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(11, 50, 261, 4)] autorelease];
    imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"top.png"];
    [self addSubview:imgView];

    imgView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(11, tableHeight+46, 261, 4)] autorelease];
    imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottom.png"];
    [self addSubview:imgView];


    CGAffineTransform myTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 10);
    [self setTransform:myTransform];
}

-(void)saveNetwork{
    CreateNetworkCommunication *communication = [[CreateNetworkCommunication alloc] init];
    communication.sourceId = [[[data objectAtIndex:selectedSource] valueForKey:@"Id"] integerValue];
    communication.name = textField.text;
    communication.delegate = self;
    [communication doRequest];
}


-(void)finishSaveNetworkRequestWithResponse:(OwnerResult*)response{
    if (response.StatusCode == 0) {

        [super dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
        [self.caller refreshNetworks];
    }
    else {
        UIAlertView *error = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:self.title message:NSLocalizedString(@"alert.error-saving", nil) delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil) otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [error show];
        [error release];
    }
}

-(void)cancel{
    [super dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:1 animated:YES];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ABC"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"ABC"] autorelease];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
    }

    if (selectedSource != indexPath.row)
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    cell.textLabel.text = [[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Name"];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //[self dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    //[self.caller didSelectRowAtIndex:indexPath.row withContext:self.context];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    selectedSource = indexPath.row;

    [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    selectedSource = indexPath.row;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [data count];
}

-(void)dealloc{
    self.data = nil;
    self.caller = nil;
    self.context = nil;
    [myTableView release];
    [super dealloc];
}





/*** THIS IS THE VIEWCONTROLLER WHERE I IMPLEMENT THE CUSTOM ALERTVIEW ***/

    #import "NetworkSelectorViewController.h"

@interface NetworkSelectorViewController ()

@end

@implementation NetworkSelectorViewController
@synthesize delegate, alert;
-(void)add {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(resizeTaxonomyView:) name:@"resizeTaxonomyView" object:nil];
    alert = [[AlertTableViewController alloc] initWithCaller:self data:sources title:@"New Network" andContext:nil];
    //UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", NSLocalizedString(@"button.new", nil), self.title] message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"button.cancel", nil) otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"button.save", nil), nil];
    //alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    //UITextField * alertTextField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];

    //UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(11, 110, 261, 200) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    //UIButton* okButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(11, 30, 50, 50)];
    //[alert addSubview:okButton];
    //okButton.frame = CGRectMake(okButton.frame.origin.x, 400, okButton.frame.size.width, okButton.frame.size.height);
    //alertTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
    //alertTextField.placeholder = self.title;
    //[alert addSubview:tableView];
    //alert.data = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2", nil];
    alert.delegate = self;
    NSLog(@"ALERT SUBVIEWS: %@", alert.subviews);
    [alert show];

    alert.frame = CGRectMake(alert.frame.origin.x, alert.frame.origin.y, alert.frame.size.width, 370);
    NSLog(@"X:%f Y:%f W:%f H:%f", alert.frame.origin.x, alert.frame.origin.y, alert.frame.size.width, alert.frame.size.height);
    UIButton* button1 = (UIButton*)[alert.subviews objectAtIndex:2];
    button1.frame = CGRectMake(0,300, 50, button1.frame.size.height);
    //[alert release];

}

- (void)resizeTaxonomyView:(NSNotification *)notification {

    // El mÈtodo recibe un objeto de tipo NSNotification cuya propiedad object
    // alberga el objeto pasado como parametro. En este caso hacemos un casting
    // del objeto a NSString.
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation))
        alert.frame = CGRectMake(alert.frame.origin.x, alert.frame.origin.y, alert.frame.size.width, 500);
    else
        alert.frame = CGRectMake(alert.frame.origin.x, alert.frame.origin.y, 500, 1000);

}
```

The NSnotification works, the method triggers, but the alertview doesnt autoresize

[uialertviewcustom](/questions/tagged/uialertviewcustom)

Comment: Avoid using having too many useless commentary in your code especially when they are not in english. Another point is try to put different files in different blocks of code so it is easier to read.